# Does ThemeShadow Class (UWP on Windows 1903) support only rectangle shapes?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try the following code which is almost the same than `example code` on Microsoft web site. Only change is that I changed first `Rectangle` to `Ellipse`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ThemeShadow x:Name="SharedShadow" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse1" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Turquoise" Shadow="{StaticResource SharedShadow}" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle1" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Turquoise" Shadow="{StaticResource SharedShadow}" />
</Grid>
```

Here is the simple C# code behind:

```
SharedShadow.Receivers.Add(BackgroundGrid);
Ellipse1.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 16);
Rectangle1.Translation += new Vector3(120, 0, 32);
```

Shadows appears on the screen but shadow connected to `Ellipse` element is still shape of rectangle. So , is it so that this new `class` support only `Rectangle` shapes like `Dialog, Grid, StackPanel` (without any `CornerRadius`) etc. but not any other shapes like `Ellipse, Text` etc.

Comment: The MSDN docs are silent about it.  All of the UIElements that automatically have a shadow are rectangular.  You have excellent evidence that this is a built-in limitation.  DropShadow may be worth a try.

Comment: On Microsoft site they told the next:  "A ThemeShadow is a preconfigured shadow effect that can be applied to any XAML element to draw shadows appropriately based on x, y, z coordinates.". So "...can be applied to any XAML element..." is true but shape of shadow is incorrect. So briefly this new API looks quite useless. The same effect can be done by DropShadow and that one support any shapes (if I remember correctly).

Comment: The point of the ThemeShadow is not the Shadow. It's the Theme. Use it if you want your shadow to match the rest of the operating system. If you want a custom shadow, then keep using DropShadow.